# Sitemaps not showing after git push

Tags: python, django, git

I have created a sitemaps for my django project but the sitemaps.py file doesn't reflect in the git repository even after i push.

i tried creating the file from git but the changes are still not reflecting

Comment: You might be on another branch... check it with `git branch`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.